# EF6 generates all the entity classes (tt .cs) in single file (eg. model.cs) and not as separate .cs file

Tags: entity-framework

I am using EF6. I have 2 tables Events and Users for which I used database first approach to generate the EDMX models and entity classes. Everything works fine but the entity classes are coming under a  single file in this case EventSample.cs(shown below). I am not getting separate files for each entity as Event.cs and User.cs. Please let me know if this is correct and if not how to rectify it?

```
public partial class Event
{
    public Event()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Creator_Id { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Events = new HashSet<Event>();
        this.Events1 = new HashSet<Event>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events1 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you install any new templates?

Comment: Code Generation Strategy = T4 . This is the property for edmx.